# MessageHandlerChain from XML as template

Tags: spring-integration

I would like to define a MessageHandlerChain in XML and then use it to create multiple isolated flows. I've evaluated the ResequencingMessageHandler but it does not fit this requirement. Also the spring-integration-flow project does not fit since it is using gateways to call the sublows.

Chain template:

```
<int:chain id="myChainTemplate">
    <int:transformer ref="inputParser"/>
    <int:service-activator ref="calculator"/>
    <int:service-activator ref="persister"/>
    <int:service-activator ref="outputSerializer"/>
    <int:service-activator ref="forwarder"/>
</int:chain>
```

Create a flow instance with a dedicated poller for each customer:

```
private final Map<String, QueueChannel> flows = new HashMap<>();
@Inject
private BeanFactory factory;
@Value("${internal.queue.capacity}")
private int queueCapacity;
@Value("${internal.poller.interval}")
private long pollerInterval;
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myChainTemplate")
private MessageHandlerChain chain;

@ServiceActivator
public void createFlowForCustomer(@Header("customer") String customer, Message<?> message) {
    QueueChannel channel = flows.get(customer);
    if (channel == null) {
        channel = new QueueChannel(queueCapacity);
        flows.put(customer, channel);
        TaskScheduler taskScheduler = IntegrationContextUtils.getTaskScheduler(factory);

        PollingConsumer poller = new PollingConsumer(channel, chain);
        poller.setTaskScheduler(taskScheduler);
        poller.setTrigger(new PeriodicTrigger(pollerInterval));
        poller.setBeanFactory(factory);
    }
    channel.send(message);
}
```

Any chance this can be done or do I have create the chain in code and wrap each handler? If I have to do it in code, is there a public method to wrap a pojo into a MessageHandler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [dynamic-ftp sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp) for a technique to programmatically create contexts (in that case for multiple outbound channel adapter).

See the dynamic-tcp-client sample (alongside the ftp sample) for a more modern technique using the Java DSL.